# materialboxed in materialize.css not working

Tags: css, reactjs, materialize

I'm trying to use materialboxed with materialize.css to open my images as a lightbox in my react app, but it does not work. people told me to use `querySelectorAll` in my `useEffect`but that does not work either.  here is my code

```
import React, {Fragment, useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import {GlobalContext} from "../../context/GlobalState";
import Parallax from "../layout/Paralex";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import M from 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js';


const Pillow = ({location, match}) => {
    const {getPillow, pillow} = useContext(GlobalContext);

    useEffect(async () => {
        getPillow(match.params.id);
        const elems = await document.querySelectorAll('.materialboxed');
        M.Materialbox.init(elems)

        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);

    if (!pillow) {
        return null
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Parallax pillow={pillow}/>
            <br/>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col s12 m6">
                    <div className="btn white green-text waves-effect waves-red">
                        <Link to="/pillows">Back to pillows</Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    {pillow.galleryImages.map(img => (
                        <div key={img.imageUrl} className="col s12 m1">
                            <img className="materialboxed responsive-img" src={img.imageUrl} alt=""/>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
```

Please assist. thanks !!

Comment: The init must always occur AFTER the element has been added to the dom, so at the end of your render.

Comment: At the end of the render, meaning within the useEffect ? Or right before the return, witch is outside of the useEffect. Also I cannot move the "M.Materialbox.init(elems)" outside the useEffect

Comment: Try both, whichever works 

Answer (score 1):

Create a ref to your image tag and then initialize the materialbox in it.

```
const imageRef = React.useRef();

React.useEffect(() => {
   M.Materialbox.init(imageRef.current);
}, [imageRef]);
```

Your image tag

```
<img className="materialboxed responsive-img" src={img.imageUrl} alt="" ref={imageRef}/>
```

It should be working now.

Answer (score 0):

You can import materialize-css like this

`import M from "materialize-css";`

and can use useEffect hook to

```
useEffect(() => {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".materialboxed");
  M.Materialbox.init(elems);
}, []);
```

It worked for me. Also, there is no need for you to make it asynchronous so you can remove it from there. If it still doesn't work maybe you have to change your useEffect to this

```
useEffect(() => {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".materialboxed");
  M.Materialbox.init(elems);
}, [pillow]);
```

Hopefully this might resolve your conflict.